# Google Data Studio - Compare months year-to-year from Google Sheets data

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm using Google Data Studio to plot the monthly revenues in our restaurant. So let's say I have a Google sheets with 2 columns:
- column A: date
- column B: day revenue

My Google sheets contains this data for several years now with on each row the day revenue for that day (see screenshot below).

I already added this Google sheet as a data source in my Google Data Studio and now I want to create a line diagram showing the 12 months and when hovering over a certain month I want to show the aggregated sums for that month over the different years (see screenshot 2 below)

How can I configure such diagram using the data in my Google sheets?

Thanks a lot for the help.

[image: Google sheets data]

[image: Google Data Studio line diagram]

Comment: Can anyone help with this? thanks :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68358224/multiple-yoy-data-in-google-data-studio-how-to-filter-to-a-specific-period

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to change the structure of your Google Sheet. Keep your singular date field but add in two columns, `Month` and `Year`.

Once you do that, create a table in Google Data Studio that uses the following fields:
- ***Dimension***: `Month`
- ***Breakdown Dimension***: `Year`
- ***Metric***: `Revenue`

Let us know how that works out!

Comment: Hi Kstat. I added two columns to my Google sheet with the MONTH(DateField) and YEAR(DateField). I resynced the Google sheet in Google Data Studio. However there seems to be something wrong with the interpretation of the Month field in Google Data Studio. I can add a table in Google Data Studio with the following configuration: Dimension of Period - DateField, Dimension - Year, Metric - Bistro Dranken (Revenue). So aggregating by year is working, but not by month. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Gotcha. Make sure the month is a string field. Do you have the option to add in a breakdown dimension? If so you want to add in Dimension - Month, Breakdown dimension - Year, Metric - Bistro Dranken

Comment: Thanks a lot kstat. I'm making progress. I was able to create a time graph now with 2018 and 2019 on the X-axis and the months 1 to 12 as the dimension breakdown, so I have twelve lines going from the revenue in 2018 to the revenue point in 2019 which is good. However the sorting is not ok. Now it's sorted as 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, ... since I don't have leading zeros. How can I add those directly in Google Data Studio? Or do I need to add them in Google sheets?

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Try one of these two things:

1) For the month field, use the date field and change the field to be view as "Month"

2) In the Google Sheet, instead of 1,2,3 etc, label them as a full date so 01/01/2019 for all of january, 02/01/2019 for all of February. Then use that field in Data Studio, but show it as Month

**To show a date field as month, click the pencil icon next to the field (as though you were editing the name) the bottom drop down field says "Show As" select month from the list.

Comment: Hi kstat. One last question: how can I combine multiple line graphs and make a total sum of for example 2 or 3 data sources? So per month and year I want to see a subtotal for that month and year over several data sources?

Comment: Hi Joël, I would recommend either combing the data into a single google sheet, or you can use the data blending feature in Google Data studio. You could use year and month as your primary key fields and then add in the metrics for each individual data source. Create your line graph as normal but create a new metric that sums together each revenue metric from your multiple data sources.

https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420?hl=en

Above is a good link on data blending in Google Data Studio